# Numbers side by side

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Ok, so here's a little puzzle I got.

- I have five *different* numbers.
- They all have *different* amount of digits.
- If you place them **side by side** you see the number 32767

How is this even possible!? And more importantly what are the five numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> binary numbers $1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111$, concatenated to yield $$111111111111111_2 = 2^{15} - 1 = 32767$$

Answer (score 0):

Putting numbers A, B, C, D, and E "side-by-side" results in

> the multiplicative expression ABCDE, which is simply the product of the five numbers.

The numbers could be

> 32767, 20, 0.05, 200000, and 0.000005, which contain 5, 2, 3, 6, and 7 digits, respectively.

Putting them side-by-side yields

> (32767)(20)(0.05)(200000)(0.000005) = 32767

With this approach, there are an infinite number of solutions.